# Hibernate mapping locations specifying?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using spring and hibernate. I have mapping locations specified as:

My folder structure is as follows:

```
src/main/resources
.
...hibernate
    .
    .....hibernate2


<property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath:hibernate/*.hbm.xml" />
```

above property is looking into only hibernate folder and is not looking into subfoders. how can i force to find hbm files in sub folders as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert a wildcard * as below

```
<property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath*:hibernate/**/*.hbm.xml" />
```